# Cordova not recognizing plugins after updating them

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I updated all the plugins I was using in cordova using the remove and add method.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
....
```

I then prepare and build

```
cordova prepare ios
cordova build ios
```

I test the app on the simulator and I get:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml
```

Why is this happening? I was under the impression that the command line was going to update everything automatically, what am I missing?

Before the rm and add everything was working fine.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles on this, I found the solution.
After updating, adding or removing plugins, you should always do this:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

That will fix any issue.

Comment: in my case, i changed cordova to ionic